# Creating a form in access that adds fields to more than table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

So I have 3 tables, and I'd like to be able to create form that will add a new row to table 1, and then use that data to add rows on table 3 with values from table 1 and 2. I've included a brief overview of the table structure. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

```
Table 1 - Things

Table 2 - TypesofThings

Table 3 - ThingType
```

Example of records in the tables:

```
Table1: 
ID - 1 Name: "This"

ID - 2 Name: "That"
```

Table2: (This table is predefined types of things capped at 15)

```
`ID - 1 TypeName: Yellow`

`ID - 2 TypeName: Red`

`ID - 3 TypeName: Green`
```

Table3: This is a "transaction" table that matches the field from table 1 to table 2

```
`ID: 1 Table1_ID:1 Table2_ID:1`

`ID: 2 Table1_ID:1 Table2_ID:2`

`ID: 3 Table1_ID:1 Table2_ID:3`

`ID: 4 Table1_ID:2 Table2_ID:2`
```

Example Form of what I'd like to be able to do:

```
Thing Name: "whatever"
[x] yellow
[] red
[x] green
```

This submission would add a row to table 1 with the name whatever, and then using the values from table 2 and 2 rows to table 3 like:

```
id:1 table1_id:1 table2_id:1
id:2 table1_id:1 table2_id:3
```

I have created the form that will add new rows, but I can't figure out how to do the rest. If you guys could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are probably going to have to use VBA to take your form inputs, update table 1, query from it, then another statement to update table 2 and 3. I don't think you can use the prebuilt forms for doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like many-to-many relationship. Conventional data entry structure:

1. single form bound to table 3 with comboboxes to select items from tables 1 and 2
2. main form bound to table 2 and subform bound to table 3 with combobox to select items from table 1
3. main form bound to table 1 and subform bound to table 3 with combobox to select items from table 2

If you want to be able to add items to table that is source for combobox 'on-the-fly' during data entry, look into the combobox NotInList event. [MS NotInList event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845736.aspx)

Comment: Is there anyway to use checkboxes instead of comboxes? I would prefer to be able to add several rows at once, and I'm guessing with this you have to select the row from table 1 and then the row from table 2 add and repeat as needed. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: How would checkboxes aid to add new records in the lookup tables 'on-the-fly'? If you mean only for the 15 items in table 2 and this table is static, then yes can use 15 controls, although radio buttons in an OptionGroup probably what you would want to allow only 1 item to be selected. I would probably prefer a listbox in lieu of 15 radio buttons.

Comment: Yeah Table 2 is static. My thought process is that a thing from table 1 can have more than one type from table 2, so I'd want to record it like 1-1-1, 2-1-2,3-1-4 where (table 3 ID, table 1 ID, Table 2 ID) I hope that I explained that correctly. Would you still approach it the same way?

Comment: If I understand correctly, table 3 is the 'junction table' that relates items from tables 1 and 2, then yes, that scenario fits the conventional approach for design of many-to-many relationship data entry forms. Structure option 3 probably best choice, no VBA required. Also, set the two FK fields in table 3 as compound index to prevent duplicate pairs.