# How to create form with 2 relations to different tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have 3 tables. One of them is "visit" table, which links to "Patients" and "Type of Visit".

[image: 3 Tables, Visits, patients, and type of visit]

I want to create form where you can fill up, visit data, and select patient and "type of visit", and if there is no patient that you need you should have the ability to create one (the same with type of visit).

I tried to do it with subforms, but I just cannot find a way to connect things.

I understand SQL, but I have no knowledge of how forms work in MS Access.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need no sub form: `patient` and `type of visit` should be a `ComboBox`s.

Comment: This is basic Access functionality and question has been asked often as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073853/creating-a-form-in-access-that-adds-fields-to-more-than-table/43076293#43076293. Perhaps you should go through an introductory tutorial. Forms are not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Conventional data entry options for many-to-many relationship:

1. single form bound to table 3 with comboboxes to select items from tables 1 and 2
2. main form bound to table 2 and subform bound to table 3 with combobox to select items from table 1
3. main form bound to table 1 and subform bound to table 3 with combobox to select items from table 2

If you want to be able to add items to table that is source for combobox 'on-the-fly' during data entry, look into the combobox NotInList event. [Combobox NotInList Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845736.aspx)